# Mysql Unknown column on update

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a column in the database but keep getting a error.

The error `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'TT' in 'field list'`

i have 2 tables `users_main` && `users_info` i need to set the value
of `users_info.JoinDate` to `users_main.created_date`.

the query

```
UPDATE users_main AS Um, (
    SELECT ua.JoinDate
    FROM users_main AS um2
    LEFT JOIN  users_info
        AS ua ON um2.ID = ua.UserID) AS TT
SET Um.created_date = TT LIMIT 40;
```

Output from the subQuery

```
+---------------------+
| JoinDate            |
+---------------------+
| 2018-01-30 12:30:53 |
| 2018-01-30 13:30:37 |
| 2018-01-30 14:31:47 |
| 2018-01-30 15:04:40 |
| 2018-01-31 02:23:55 |
| 2018-02-02 09:43:59 |
| 2018-02-02 09:50:48 |
| 2018-02-02 09:55:09 |
| 2018-02-02 15:10:31 |
| 2018-02-02 18:43:49 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: `TT` is a subquery alias, not a column alias.

Comment: `= TT.JoinDate`'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SET Um.created_date = TT` should be `SET Um.created_date = TT.JoinDate`.

But don't need the subquery, just a regular join between the two tables.

```
UPDATE users_Main as um
LEFT JOIN users_info AS ui ON um.ID = ui.UserID
SET um.created_date = ui.JoinDate
LIMIT 40
```

Note that `LEFT JOIN` will set `created_date` to `NULL` if there's no matching row in `users_info`. If you want to leave these rows alone, use `INNER JOIN`.